# How to check if a string is inside another string (but not on the edge)?

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have this string: `abc/def`. How would I check if there is a slash inside the string but not on the edge? For example, a slash at the very end like `abcdef/` or the very start like `/abcdef` is not allowed.

In this case, `String#includes` doesn't work since that includes all possible locations. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Would `abc/def/` result in `true` or `false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a substring and check with includes.

```js
const check = s => s.slice(1, -1).includes('/');

console.log(['abc/def', '/def', 'abc/'].map(check));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple regex to check the string:

```js
"abc/def".test(/.\/./) // true
"/abcdef".test(/.\/./) // false
"abcdef/".test(/.\/./) // false
```

Alternatively, you could get the index of the `/` and compare it with the length of the string.

```js
const str = "abc/def"

const i = str.indexOf("/")
i > 0 && i < str.length - 1 // true
```

You could also use `inside-string`:

```js
const insideString = require("inside-string")
insideString("abc/def", "/") // true
```

Comment: When you use indexOf, you can also use lastIndexOf to look for slash from the end. If the string might be 'abc/a/', str.indexOf will return you 1st index it meets.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression:

```js
function test(input, search) {
  return new RegExp(`^.+${search}.+$`).test(input);
}

console.log(test("abcde/f", "\/"));
console.log(test("abcdef/", "\/"));
```